# How Can I simulate Return KeyPress within BashScript for Expo Build Process

Tags: bash

My current script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd Desktop/work-directory/project-directory/
code .
npx expo run:ios -d
sleep 10
xdotool key Return
```

- I navigate to a directory I open every morning for work.
- I open my text editor.
- I run the `npx expo run:ios -d` command to run my build on my local device.
- You can read more about it here if you are interested: (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/run-on-device/)
- After running `npx expo run:ios -d` I am asked to "Select a simulator" where I pick which simulated device I want to create the build for.
- I always build it on my local device. Considering it's the first option available, I just want the above script to press Return/Enter when prompted to continue building the app without me having to be by the terminal.

From an outsiders perspective, might anyone be able to shed some light on what I might be doing wrong? Is my syntax wrong? Does someone know if I have to use any different tools from `xdotool` to interact with the Expo CLI prompt? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

- I already tried using `yes` and that did not work. I specifically need enter or return.
- I have adjusted sleep to over 30 seconds to see if that does it.
- I have read about `Expect` and unsure if that is the route I want to go/the tool I even need.

Thank you so much and I look forward to hearing from y'all within the Bash community :)

Comment: Having no experience with `xdotool`, I wonder how this program should know in **which** window it should simulate the return key, i.e. shouldn't there be a [_windowactivate_](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/)? Another point to investigate would be, how Expo CLI reads its answer. If it comes from stdin, a simple redirection should do the job. If it is a X Window application, I think `xdotool` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: You make a great point. After pressing `Ctrl` + `c` within the Expo CLI prompt, I saw that it did in fact run the keyPress command, just after and then I realized it never does it, in the window I want it to. I no longer believe xdotool will work for my purposes within the terminal window. All examples I have seen have been for web browser. I have read up on some stdin stdout, and stderr now and will look into what I might have to do to redirect it as you say. If you have any good reading resources. I would be more than happy to give them a look. Thank you for your assistance and consideration

Comment: Basically, with _xdotool_ you have to identify the window to which the key presses have to be sent (manually, you simply put the focus on that window), and whatever process happens to run in that window at that time, receives the key input. With stdin, you don't send _keys_, but _characters_, and the target is a process, not a window. Of course the process must be willing to read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the manual [page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xdotool.1.html), , look for the reference to "Navigator".

That gives an example of how to make xdotool locate the window associated with your **npx expo** process, so that it can then send that signal to it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I actually didn't need to simulate a return keyPress to automate one of the commands within the Expo CLI

I was able to come to a solution by using the following tool: FIG (https://fig.io/)

When I would input `npx expo run:ios -d`, before pressing enter like I usually do, fig had auto populated the device id to go after `-d`. Which made the whole command look something like this `npx expo run:ios -d 00008030-000537H31B5573F` (Numbers and letters have been changed).
This alone allowed me to essentially respond to one of Expo's interactive prompts by providing the device id before it was ever asked.

Hopefully this can help someone else in the future. Cheers.